# MAMP all virtual hosts point to htdocs folder

Tags: php, apache, mamp, virtualhost

I've read through all the questions I could find but none of them have worked for me. I'm trying to set up a couple of virtual hosts on my MAMP apache install. Currently, typing localhost takes me to my htdocs as expected. However, typing mysite.dev should take me to another directory but it instead drops me off at htdocs.

**hosts**

```
##
# Host Database
#
#
# localhost is used to configure the lookback interface
# when the system is booting. Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1        localhost
127.0.0.1      mysite.dev

255.255.255.255 broadcasthost


::1         localhost
fe80::1%lo0  localhost
```

I've uncommented in **httpd.conf**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And I've set up my **httpd-vhosts.conf** a bunch of different ways with the same result. The current state is:

```
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mysite.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/public"
    ServerName mysite.dev
    ServerAlias www.mysite.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/mysite.dev"
    CustomLog "logs/mysite.dev" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 2):

You might miss some steps. First of all

1. run mamp with apache 80 and mysql 3306 port. this will automatically change the httpd.conf file with those port. close mamp
2. go to httpd.conf and go to line: 575 and uncomment this line from

   ```
   # Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
   ```

   to

   ```
   Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
   ```

   If it is not line 575  search with the text and u will find the line.
3. Next in httpd-vhosts.conf, add your virtual urls/hosts. sample below

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Project"
      ServerName dev.project.com
      ServerAlias www.dev.project.com
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   dev.project.com is just sample and you can name it however you want. server alias is optional but better to keep it just likeserver name but with an extra "www." as it is shown above.
4. next add those to hosts file like

   ```
   127.0.0.1       dev.project.com
   ```

   better to add all possibilities like below

   ```
   127.0.0.1       dev.project.com   http://dev.project.com   www.dev.project.com    http://www.dev.project.com
   ```
5. save the hosts file and restart mamp. Cheers!!!

**I THINK YOU GUYS MISSED STEP 2**